# How do you use a val returned inside a function in a class?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm trying to take user input, run it through if statements so the correct math is multiplied, and then output it for a user to see their total. When I end the return statement in my function, it won't let me use the variable the number should be stored in. If I don't end the statement, my code is unreachable.
Any guidance appreciated.

```
package com.example.awcc
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class Setup: AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle ? ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        editTextNumber.text.toString().toInt()
    }
}


class ThirdActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle ? ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3)

        val button2 = findViewById < Button > (R.id.button2)
        button2.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        val button3 = findViewById < Button > (R.id.button3)
        button3.setOnClickListener {
            val intent2 = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent2)

            val button7 = findViewById < Button > (R.id.button)
            button7.setOnClickListener {
                fun accessory(): Int {
                    var value1 = editTextNumber.text.toString().toInt()
                    if (value1 > 10) {
                        return value1 * 0
                    } else if (value1 in 10. .20) {
                        return value1 * 1
                    } else if (value1 in 21. .40) {
                        return value1 * 2
                    } else if (value1 in 40. .50) {
                        return value1 * 3
                    } else if (value1 in 51. .75) {
                        return value1 * 4
                    } else if (value1 < 75) {
                        return value1 * 5
                    }
                    return value1
                }

                val final2 = value1.toString().toInt()

                val complete = final2.toString()
                try {
                    editTextNumber7 ? .setText(complete)
                } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        applicationContext,
                        "Please enter a 0 in the blank field",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                    accessory()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `when` to simplify your code and take the `value1` to function outside.

```
    var value1 = editTextNumber.text.toString().toInt()

    fun accessory(): Int {
        
        return when {

            value1 > 10 -> value1 * 0

            value1 in 10..20 -> value1 * 1

            value1 in 21..40 -> value1 * 2

            value1 in 40..50 -> value1 * 3

            value1 in 51..75 -> value1 * 4

            value1 < 75 -> value1 * 5

            else -> value1
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. Because you are trying to use the "value1" variable outside the method in which you have declared. You can't use the local variable outside of its scope.

```
            //Existing
            val final2 = value1.toString().toInt()

            val complete = final2.toString()
            try {
                    editTextNumber7?.setText(complete)
            } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    applicationContext,
                    "Please enter a 0 in the blank field",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
                accessory()
            }

            //Replace with this code
            val complete = accessory().toString()
            try {
                    editTextNumber7?.setText(complete)
            } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    applicationContext,
                    "Please enter a 0 in the blank field",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            }
```

Comment: It still isnt working and I have no clue why at this point.